# Resetting onbeforeunload via iframe trigger

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an iframe that is loaded in dynamically via JS, this is from a different domain, however I can't seem to reset the onbeforeunload via codes such as:

```
$("iframe button").click(function(){
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });

            $(document).on("click", "iframe button",function(){
                window.parent.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
```

I've tried different variations of this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you also please post the HTML and JS code for the iFrame?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's just a simple HTML page and the JS is loaded in from 3rd party order form